# Issue to understand why the code does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring.  So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz" yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same place in both strings.

For this problem i wrote the following code :

```
  def string_match(a, b):
     result  = 0
     tiniest = b
     biggest = a
     if len(a) < 2 or len(b) < 2:
      return 0

     if len(a) < len(b):
       tiniest = a
       print('tiniest is {} and size minus 1 equals 
  {}'.format(str(tiniest), len(tiniest)-1))
       biggest = b
     else:
       tiniest = b
       print('ELSE tiniest is {} and size minus 1 equals {}'.format(str(tiniest), len(tiniest) - 1))
       biggest = a

       for i in range(len(tiniest) - 1):
         print(i)
         if tiniest[i:i+2] == biggest[i:i+2]:
             print('tiniest is {} and biggest is {} and i is 
  {}'.format(tiniest[i:i+2], biggest[i:i+2], i))
             result = result + 1
         else:
            continue
         print("result is ",result)
     return result
```

**So for the test :**
string_match('helloooo', 'hello') or string_match('hello', 'hello')   => no problem the function returns 4 as expected

But as soon as the first parameter is smaller than the second, nothing works any longer, for a reason i do not understand:
string_match('hell', 'hello') => does nothing , why ???

I can't see the difference between my solution and the official solution of this problem which is:

```
def string_match(a, b):
    # Figure which string is shorter.
    shorter = min(len(a), len(b))
    count = 0

    # Loop i over every substring starting spot.
    # Use length-1 here, so can use char str[i+1] in the loop
    for i in range(shorter - 1):
        a_sub = a[i:i + 2]
        b_sub = b[i:i + 2]
        if a_sub == b_sub:
            count = count + 1

    return count
```

Also is it ok to init the variables  **result tiniest** and **biggest** at the beginning of the function ?

thank you

Comment: For loop is indented inside the else condition, which might be the problem.

Comment: Do you accept a different solution which is better than you currently have?

Comment: @ksholla20 you might be definitely right.

Comment: @Austin of course i accept i just couldn't see why my code didn't work. But that is due to the bad indentation...iam new to python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually an indentation issue. The for loop was inside the else indentation. Putting the for loop at the same level of the else statement, solved it:

```
def string_match(a, b):
   result  = 0
   tiniest = b
   biggest = a
   if len(a) < 2 or len(b) < 2:
    return 0

   if len(a) < len(b):
     tiniest = a
     print('tiniest is {} and size minus 1 equals {}'.format(str(tiniest), len(tiniest)-1))
     biggest = b
   else:
     tiniest = b
     print('ELSE tiniest is {} and size minus 1 equals {}'.format(str(tiniest), len(tiniest) - 1))
     biggest = a


   for i in range(len(tiniest) - 1):
     print(i)
     if tiniest[i:i+2] == biggest[i:i+2]:
       print('tiniest is {} and biggest is {} and i is {}'.format(tiniest[i:i+2], biggest[i:i+2], i))
       result = result + 1
     else:
       continue
   print("result is ",result)
   return result
```